# Set a new value in an XML file with powershell

Tags: powershell

I cant correctly insert the string i need as value,

I have this line of code replacing a value in a xml file:

```
 $XML.Task.Actions.Arguments = '-File `"' + $RootDir + '\' + $Folderpath + "\RunningTasks\workScheduler.ps1"`"
```

I want it to replace the value with this: 
-File "C:\Workstation\Delivery\RunningTasks\workScheduler.ps1"

But i cant get the correct format in the way that the " characters are correct formatted.

Anyone that could point me in the correct direction? I have tried for a few days now :/

//Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a hard time understanding the exact request,the XML or rest of the code would probably clear it up. Regardless I took a stab at it, if it's just to replace that one line in the XML this should work.

```
[xml]$data =  Get-Content -Path C:\Path\to\your\xml\File.Xml

$data.Task.Actions.Arguments = 'C:\Workstation\Delivery\RunningTasks\workScheduler.ps1'

$data.save('C:\Path\to\your\xml\File.Xml')
```